# Flex Mobile Android full screen application at startup

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, startup

I'm developing and Android application using the Flex 4.6 SDK version and AIR 4.0 SDK.

The application has the following manifest parameters (among others):

```
        <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
        <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
        <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
```

and:

```
<application android:enabled="true">
        <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                    </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

So as you may see, the configuration is intended to launch the application as the HOME app, in landscape mode as soon as the device starts.

The application does in fact do everything it's supposed to but when the device boots up, the app does not starts in full screen because you can see the notification/status bar. Next you may see the problem.

[image]

What I need to do is to make the app start at full screen when the device boots. Now, the only way to make it start at full screen mode is to restart the application after the device finished booting up.

I hope you can help me solve this anoying problem.

**EDIT 1**

I also compiled the application using AIR 14 SDK and the behaiviour was exactly the same.

I must add that sometimes, the status bar appears and sometimes it doesn't. I thought it had something to do with the WIFI network connection but it doesn't, since on both cases, as soon as the application, if it has inmediate network connection or if it doesn't, the status bar will sometimes appear and sometimes not appear.

**EDIT 2**

Further testing make me realize that when the status bar was showing, it was exactly the same scenario as when the **fullscreen** parameter of the manifest was set to false. Could it be something related to a bug in that parameter or something like that?

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: Hello Josh. I'm working on Android 4.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

just go into the manifest and use a full screen theme.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```